# Download bulk objects from Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a large bucket folder with over 30 million object (images). Now, I need to download only 700,000 object (image) from that large folder. 
I have the names of objects (images) that I need to download in a .txt file.

I can use AWS CLI, but not sure if it support downloading many objects at one command.

Is there a straight forward solution for that you would have in mind?

Comment: How do you normally use AWS CLI to download even one image from your bucket folder? Where do you want to download to, your local computer or to the virtual computer you have on amazon EC2?

Comment: Options for running a command repeatedly with parameters taken from text file: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149726/how-to-pass-each-line-of-a-text-file-as-an-argument-to-a-command and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176565.aspx

Comment: Also, if retrieving this many objects is really challenging in terms or orchestration and performance, you might want to consider using s3distcp on EMR, driven by a manifest of the files to download. That would get the files to your EMR cluster from which you can do whatever you need.

Comment: I download the images to local driver and use the below command 
aws s3 cp s3://<bucket_name>/images/ path/to/local/machine/images

There seems another issue too, the downloaded images seems corrupt.